# detecting vowels in python

Tags: python, if-statement

I tried looking for a already answered question similar to this but my problem seems to be different.
basically the user enters a letter and if its a vowel it should display a congratulatory message otherwise a "you lose" message

```
    letter = str(input('enter any letter '))
    if letter == ('a'or 'e'or 'i'or 'o' or'u'):
         print('congratulations you won')
    else: print('sorry you lose , better luck next time')
```

for some reason it only displays congratulatory message when I enter 'a' and will not work if i enter any of the other vowels, 
also I would like to know if there is any other way to simplify this without having to write an "or" between every option for future reference.
thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `('a' or 'e' ...)` line always evaluates to 'a', and that is what the `letter` variable is being compared to.

Try:

```
if letter in 'aeiou':
    ...
```

Comment: I would add 'y' too. It should still count! poor y. :P